# combine mutiple movie clip functions into a single swc file or MXP file For Flash Action Script 3.0?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, swc

I have to build one MXP package for Flash (not Flex). But i have multiple components, somthing like HelpSymbolMovieClips(have its on class), one image holder. etc. I need to combine there swc file into a single MXP file. Is it possible?

or

How can i make a all these multi movieClip functionality in a single SWC file. Am bit confused about the structure of the component which is having multiple functions/MoiveClips. like (Image gallery components.

I have a little knowledge about how to create a swc. and i created one component from the help of a [tutorial](http://flexion.wordpress.com/2007/06/27/building-flash-cs3-components/) so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can use the Flex SDK that ships with Flash CS4 to assets within your Flash application and then export as a swc file. Something like:

```
[Embed("bullet_star.png")]
```

You should be able to use your swf movie clips instead of an image.

For example:

In Flash CS4, select File > New and select “Flash File (ActionScript 3.0)”.
Save the .FLA document to your hard drive and paste a .PNG file named bullet_star.png in the same directory as the .FLA file.
Paste the following code into the Actions panel:

```
// ActionScript 3.0
/**
 *  Note: This example assumes the bullet_star.png file
 *  is in the same directory as your .FLA file.
 */

[Embed("bullet_star.png")]
const BulletStar:Class;

var starIcon:DisplayObject = new BulletStar();
starIcon.x = 10;
starIcon.y = 10;
addChild(starIcon);
```

This will prompt you that you are using a feature that requires the Flex SDK.

To learn how to do this see: http://actionscriptexamples.com/2008/10/26/using-the-flex-sdk-with-flash-cs4/